# How to make a smart contract which pays out only if a service is performed?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, tokens, payable, payments

Hello I am new to the world of solidity.

I am trying to create a **smart contract** with the following **conditions**:

- a customer wants to buy a service/product from a retailer (me).
- the price of my service (in tokens) is dictated by me and can be changed in the future
- the tokens must be on hold until i perform my service
- the tokens are released to my account only if I perform my service otherwise they are sent back to the customer.

Are you aware of some **project**, **tutorial** or **documentation** similar to what I want to achieve so that i could learn from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term to implement you are looking for is called atomic transactions. Just look for atomic transactions in ethereum.